# GIT: My Teammate cannot pull the changes I pushed

Tags: git

I am beyond new to GIT, and infact have set it up almost like SVN (my comfort zone).  There is a "single" remote repository which we are both pushing and pulling changes from off of a single master branch.  I pushed a number of changes, which I then pulled into a fourth location (production server) so I know my changes made it to the "single" remote repository.

My git push yields "everything up-to-date" message.

How do I go about debugging the situation.  I assume the issue is on his end, but i don't even know how to guide him on the investigation. Nor can I find any source of logging.

Any help on an approach to diagnosing the problem would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the exact command that he gives and what is the output he receives?

Comment: I 'git clone' the repo before, so I just 'git pull'. It works before but not now.

Comment: Ok what exactly he says when you issue the pull. Also put the pull command

Comment: Maybe you have changed your copy in away that git pull has conflicts in merge?

Comment: Could you show us the trace?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you have pushed what you want.
check the output of:

- `git branch -avv` (to see if you have an active branch, or if you are in [detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309))
- `git log` (to check the last most recent SHA1 on your branch)
- `git ls-remote origin` (to see if that same SHA1 has indeed been pushed)

Then you can repeat those checks on the production side, to see why a `git pull` wouldn't fetch and merge that most recent SHA1 that you have pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents :

Say you have two branches with the following commits (IN NO ORDER, but from left to right):

```
person   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Master   1 2 3 4 5 6 9
```

Now, when the guy in `person` branch tries to pull `master`, git finds that there is a commit in branch which Master does not have. The pull is essentially a `merge` of the two branches. In this case, the guy at `person` branch can do :

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git pull origin Master
git add ##### Whatever Files #####
git commit -m "10" 
git push origin person
```

What he just did is that he reset commit numbers 7 and 8, but kept the code that had been changed as a result of them. He is not at the same commit level as `master` and can hence pull in number 9. He can push the changes back now. the person branch is now :

```
person   1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10
```

Or, he could also `reset` and then `stash` his changes and then apply the `stash`.

Now, it so happens that at times, a user may find his remote to be different from the place he is pulling from. In that case, simply check `git remove -v` and if necessary, change it to the correct link from where you cloned `git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here`

He could also be having problems fetching the correct branch. In this case, he should do :

```
`git fetch`
```

which will pull ALL the remote branches and then do a `git checkout branchName`

Hope this helps.